# XSS prevention, minimal implementation

Tags: java, xss

In our project in order to prevent XSS we added filter (HttpServletFilter) that simply escapes all occurrences of "<" and ">" in Json (wrapping user input) like:

```
json = json.replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;");
```

Question is: Is above enough to guarantee that XSS will never happen?

Or (in other words) can you provide example of user input that will cause XSS like behavior in our system?

Update: thanks to some useful answers, I understand that XSS still possible in case user input is used as source for href attribute or directly in javascript. 
E.g. in case where triangle brackets already present on the their place around potential user input appearance.

But we never use user input data this way. 
Any other suggestions?

Comment: This may also change some places where `<`or `>` appearance is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, it's not enough

Please go read the [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) which explains the different contexts where XSS can occur.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not be sure. For example ([from here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)):

```
<a href="{{anURL}}">
```

XSS Attack:

```
anURL = "javascript:alert(1)"
```

or

```
<script>var aPage = {{aVar}};</script>
```

XSS Attack:

```
aVar = "1;alert(1)"
```

You also could find some material from [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/252985) or a sample implementation how to do it better on [Github](https://gist.github.com/daogurtsov/7741368). A more detailled answered you may find on [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/73966).

Comment: Useful answer. Thank you. In our app however, we never use user input as value for href (or any other) attribute or directly in context of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately It's not enough to escape triangle brackets. For example your site probably has some JavaScript code which deals with user input data. Someone could insert something malicious in a user input field and it would be executed directly by your JavaScript code.  The malicious data would not need to contain triangle brackets because it is being injected straight into the JavaScript.

This old article is a good starting point. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/252985